# Returning a string from a method in Rust

Tags: rust

> Editor's note: The syntax in this question predates Rust 1.0 and the 1.0-updated syntax generates different errors, but the overall concepts are still the same in Rust 1.0.

I have a struct T with a `name` field, I'd like to return that string from the `name` function. I don't want to copy the whole string, just the pointer:

```
struct T {
     name: ~str,
}

impl Node for T {
     fn name(&self) -> &str { self.name }
     // this doesn't work either (lifetime error)
     // fn name(&self) -> &str { let s: &str = self.name; s }
}

trait Node {
     fn name(&self) -> &str;
}
```

Why is this wrong? What is the best way to return an `&str` from a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to take a reference to `self.name` and ensure that the lifetimes of `&self` and `&str` are the same:

```
struct T {
    name: String,
}

impl Node for T {
    fn name<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        &self.name
    }
}

trait Node {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}
```

You can also use *lifetime elision*, as shown in the trait definition. In this case, it automatically ties together the lifetimes of `self` and the returned `&str`.

Take a look at these book chapters:

- [References and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html)
- [Lifetime syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html)

Comment: So I got it working with `fn name<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str { let s: &'a str = self.name; s }` is there any way for it work without the let binding?

Comment: I had in my memory that ~ to & conversioon worked, maybe was changed (or was always just for fuction parameters?), you have to just call as_slice

Comment: @cloudhead, for strings or owned vectors (`~[T]`) you have to call `as_slice()`. For other boxed types `&*value` should suffice. This will probably change when dynamically sized types land.